# Get dynamic variable for SQL insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (SPECIAL_ID, 62, 0, 1, -1, NULL, NULL, -1)
WHERE sp_id IN (SELECT id = SPECIAL_ID
                FROM foo
                WHERE lock IS NULL)
```

`SPECIAL_ID` is not yet defined, but it should be equal to the `id` that comes from the inner `SELECT` statement from `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dont use values, use a select

```
INSERT INTO my_table (need To declare list of column names for table insert)
Select SPECIAL_ID, 62, 0, 1, -1, NULL, NULL, -1
From Table
WHERE sp_id IN(
    SELECT id = SPECIAL_ID
    FROM foo
    WHERE lock IS NULL
)
```

If there is no table for the sp_id to be in, you could get rid of that where caluse and move the sub select up like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (need To declare list of column names for table insert)
Select SPECIAL_ID, 62, 0, 1, -1, NULL, NULL, -1    
FROM foo
WHERE lock IS NULL
```

Comment: What is `Table` ?

Comment: Where ever the Special_ID is.  You may be able to get rid of the where sp_id IN , and just select the values From foo where lock IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SPECIAL_ID, 62, 0, 1, -1, NULL, NULL, -1 
INTO my_table 
FROM your_source_table 
WHERE sp_id in (SELECT id = SPECIAL_ID
               FROM foo
               WHERE lock IS NULL)
```

Listing column names is not necessary unless their ordinal position is different or you are only applying this to certain columns, not all of them